# Python turtlegraphics inconsistency between different OS's

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, graph-coloring

I'm drawing a fairly simple shape using Python's `turtle` module and the code below:

```
import turtle

turtle.color('black', '#fef00e')
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.left(180)
turtle.forward(100)
for i in range(5):
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(100+50*i)
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

Strangely enough, this produces two different results on Windows (left) and all other OS's I've tried (Ubuntu, Arch, OSX). Areas with an even number of overlapping fillings are still filled on Windows, but blanked out again for others. Can anyone explain me what the reason for this is, and if there is any way to influence it? It seems weird that this behaviour would be so inconsistent.

[image] [image]

It seems that this is a design choice as well; it is not immediately obvious to me which of the two is the 'correct' version.

Comment: They're probably using different fill rules for some reason. The left one would be [non-zero winding rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule) and the right one [even-odd rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is whether 'fill' means 'color' or 'switch color' on a particular system.  To color twice is to color.  To switch twice is to not switch.  (This pair is the basis of Spencer Brown's "Laws of Form".)  Turtle is implemented on top of Tkinter.  Here is a simple Tkinter program that reproduces the left figure on Windows (though without the black lines, which turtle adds).  I strongly suspect that you would get the right figure on *nix (I don't have one at the moment).

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canv = Canvas(root, width=800, height=800)
canv.pack()
l = canv.create_polygon(
        500,400, 400,400, 400,300, 550,300,
        550,500, 300,500, 300,200, 500,400, fill='yellow')
root.mainloop()
```

If so, then I suspect the different is a result of the underlying graphics system and which interpretation it gives to 'fill'.

I looked in the [tk manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M105) but found nothing about the meaning of filling twice, just '-fill color'.

Comment: I can confirm that this does indeed reproduce the same difference. I was suspecting that it was the underlying graphics library that's causing this difference, as the Python code running on both platforms is identical (down to the compiled CPython underneath).